# Meteor : best strategy for a search engine in a collection

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a meteor project featuring products. They are all in a `Products` collection.

At the moment, I have only 50 of them. So I subscribe to the entire collection and then filter it client side.

Bu what if my project gets a lots of products. Let's say 10.000. This strategy won't work at all. The application will be slow and will take like forever to load the first datas. What would be the most efficient ?

1 => the classic way : no subscription, I just make meteor method server side and I make calls client side to get the data I want. (this one, I know how to build)

2 => the more *meteory* way (I feel more into that one) : make a subscription, but filtered and paginated. Meteor.subscribe('products', );

Is it viable on a large scale ? And how do I achieve that ? I'm not sure how to start with the pagination stuff. Do I update my subscription or start a new one ?

I use iron-router. And the first problem I have to tackle is caching the result. In a perfect world, if a user makes a first search, then an other and then goes back to the first one, I'd like the app to keep the first results. When I put my subscription in the `waitOn` hook, all the datas are lost when I go on another route.

Comment: Have you had a look at [discover meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/)? The chapter on pagination covers most of this in detail. They use "infinite" pagination (long list with a next button) rather than traditional page-based pagination. The former seems to fit the notion of subscriptions in a more obvious way.

Comment: I will look at it in detail. Thank you.